# Can I turn on bitlocker again after installing Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

When I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 it asked to disable Bitlocker. I did and installed Ubuntu. Now can I turn on bitlocker again?

Comment: "*it asked*" who/what is "it"?  Bitlocker does not have anything to do with Ubuntu and Ubuntu can't do anything with Bitlocker encryption.  This question about Bitlocker may be better answered on SuperUser

Comment: @Nmath the OP is referring to the Ubuntu installer. It does indeed ask the user to disable Bitlocker in Windows in order to continue the installation. The installer even links to https://help.ubuntu.com/bitlocker for more information. But that page fails to mention whether or not you can turn it back on after installation. I am going to try and do this.

Comment: Judging from this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263024/ubuntu-20-04-windows-10-pro-disk-encryption?rq=1 it might cause some unwanted side effects.

Comment: @TimothyP Anecdotally, I have *never* had a problem with this and I've been dual booting LUKS encrypted Ubuntu alongside BitLocker encrypted Windows as long as BitLocker has been around. I also generally reinstall both OS after the first point release of a LTS.  I believe disabling BitLocker is only required if you don't provide unpartitioned free space for the Ubuntu installer.  That's only because the installer can't even see where Windows begins and ends. **Of course** you can reenable bitlocker encryption after Ubuntu is finished installing: they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: OP should add more details and explain the problem. There is nothing that needs to be done in Ubuntu to deal with BitLocker encryption in Windows. This should be a non-issue. If we are to be asked for a solution, we need to know what isn't working.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question. The Ubuntu installer tells the user to disable Bitlocker if you try to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Can you then re-enable Bitlocker in Windows after installing Ubuntu, or will that cause problems? I think it's fine, but you need some addition steps if you want to access the Windows partition from Ubuntu.

Comment: If you never set up any explicit recovery keys for bitlocker, it relies on some of the PCR registers, which may change when firmware is updated or maybe another OS installed. Just to be on the safe side, disable it, install/flash... then reenable it. Best to definitely have at least one other recovery mechanism.